# Bootstrap modal closing immediately, should delay

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

In this example clicking on the `contact` tab on the nav menu will open up a bootstrap modal.  If the user enters in a string into the modal's text box of less than 10, there's a warning and the modal doesn't close.  If the string is greater than ten then a message will be appended to the modal saying something like `success...` and the modal should delay for a spell and then disappear.  With the current code the validation part and the modal showing up works, but there is no delay before it dissappears.  Why isn't the current code working and how can I fix it?

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BAJ8X/)
js

```
$(document).ready(function () {

            $('#modalClose').click(function () {
                var validResult = getLength('#tbName', 10);
                if (validResult) {
                    var successMessage = $('<div>').text('Successfully saved to database...').css('color', 'green');
                    $('.modal-body').append(successMessage);
                    $('#contact').delay(5000).modal('hide');
                }
                else {
                    alert('input did not meet validation, try again');
                    $('#tbName').val('').focus();
                }
            });
            function getLength(el, x) {
                var len = $(el).val().length
                return len > x
            }
            $('#contact').on('hide.bs.modal', function () {
                $('#tbName').val('');
            });
            $('#contact').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
                $('#tbName').focus();
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should use [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.setTimeout) instead of `delay`, [delay](http://api.jquery.com/delay/#entry-longdesc) works on animation queues.

```
  window.setTimeout(function(){
     $('#contact').modal('hide');
  }, 2000); //2000 milliseconds i.e 2 seconds, you can change it to the value as you need
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/MQ6We/)**

Comment: Perfect. Why is it we have to use the window object here?

Comment: @wootscootinboogie well. Its just to have it say explicitly. You don't need to do it in this case but if you have a closure which has another implementation for setTimeout and you actually want to invoke the one of that of the window this helps....

Answer (score 1):

I would just go for the plain javascript method of setting a timeout:

```
if (validResult) {
                var successMessage = $('<div>').text('Successfully saved to database...').css('color', 'green');
                $('.modal-body').append(successMessage);
                window.setTimeout(function() { 
                $('#contact').modal('hide'); }, 500);
            }
```

This is only configured for .5 seconds (5 seconds felt kind of long), but this works in the attached fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/BAJ8X/4/